# How best to retrieve AWS SSM parameters from the AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-cdk, aws-ssm

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I'm going a bit snowblind with blogs and articles trying to find a solution.

I'm trying to use the AWS CDK to deploy a Stack - specifically a CloudFront Distribution layered over an S3 Bucket. I want to retrieve a cert from Cert Manager, and I also want to update a Hosted Zone in R53.

I want to put the zone ID and cert ARN in SSM Parameter Store, and have my CDK app pull the correct ID/ARN from there, so as not to leave it in my code.

I'm currently pulling the values like this in my Go code:

```
certArn := awsssm.StringParameter_ValueFromLookup(stack, certArnSSM)
certificate := awscertificatemanager.Certificate_FromCertificateArn(stack, wrapName("certificate"), certArn)
```

Where `certArnSSM` is the path to the parameter.

However, when  I run the `synth` I get this:

```
panic: "ARNs must start with \"arn:\" and have at least 6 components: dummy-value-for-/dev/placeholder/certificateArn"
```

From some [reading](https://sdhuang32.github.io/ssm-StringParameter-valueFromLookup-use-cases-and-internal-synth-flow/), this is expected. However, I'm not sure on the 'best practice' approach to solving it. I'm not totally clear on how to use `Lazy` to solve this - do I need to create a `type` and implement the `Produce()` method?

Comment: What is the cached `certArn` parameter value  in `cdk.context.json`?

Comment: When it fails, it doesn't get that far - no `cdk.context.json` is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to replicate your error.  The following synths and deploys without error, correctly retrieving the `certArn` param from `ssm` as a valid certificate arn lookup input:

```golang
func NewCertLookupStack(scope constructs.Construct, id string, props *awscdk.StackProps) awscdk.Stack {
    stack := awscdk.NewStack(scope, &id, &props)

    certArn := awsssm.StringParameter_ValueFromLookup(stack, jsii.String("/dummy/certarn"))
    certificate := awscertificatemanager.Certificate_FromCertificateArn(stack, jsii.String("Certificate"), certArn)

    awscdk.NewCfnOutput(stack, jsii.String("ArnOutput"), &awscdk.CfnOutputProps{
        Value: certificate.CertificateArn(), // demonstrate it works: the correct cert arn storeed as a stack output
    })

    return stack
}
```

Comment: Yes - I also created a simple function just to test it, and got the same result. It may be because I was passing the value in to a CloudFront Distribution, and at some point whilst the value of the Cert ARN is still `dummy-value`, there's some validation that fails. I'm not sure. I'll take another look this weekend if I get time!

Comment: I've redone the required code and can't replicate the problem. Who knows what's going on, this drove me mad for about an hour the other day...

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the issue by making the UUID of the cert a variable in my code, and then constructing an ARN manually. It feels like the wrong way to solve the problem though.

```golang
createdArn := jsii.String(fmt.Sprintf("arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:%s:certificate/%s", *sprops.Env.Account, certUuid))
certificate := awscertificatemanager.Certificate_FromCertificateArn(stack, wrapName("certificate"), createdArn)
```