# jsii.errors.JSIIError: ARNs must start with "arn:" and have at least 6 components

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-ssm

Similar issues but not in python cdk  :  [How best to retrieve AWS SSM parameters from the AWS CDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70759640/how-best-to-retrieve-aws-ssm-parameters-from-the-aws-cdk)

Hi I am saving a arn in ssm and my variable name is like this

```
test-value-for-my-job-executor-new-function-lambda-arn
```

and when I try to get this using ssm like this

```
 from aws_cdk import aws_ssm as ssm 
my_arn = ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(self, "test-value-for-my-job-executor-new-function-lambda-arn")
self.scan_pre_process = _lambda.Function.from_function_arn(self, "my-job-executor", my_arn)
```

I get this error

**jsii.errors.JSIIError: ARNs must start with "arn:" and have at least 6 components: dummy-value-for-test-value-for-my-job-executor-new-function-lambda-arn**

even I tried to increase name of this still same issue .

Answer (score 0):

`value_from_lookup` is a [Context Method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html#context_methods). It looks up the SSM Parameter's cloud-side value once at synth-time and caches its value in `cdk.context.json`. Context methods return dummy variables until they resolve. That's what's happening in your case. CDK is trying to use `my_arn` before the lookup has occurred.

There are several fixes:

1. Quick-and-dirty: Comment out the `_lambda.Function.from_function_arn` line. Synth the app. Uncomment out the line. This simply forces the caching to happen before the value is used.
2. Hardcode the Lambda ARN into `_lambda.Function.from_function_arn`. If the Function name and version/alias are stable, no real downside to hardcoding. Tip: use the [Stack.format_arn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk/Stack.html#aws_cdk.Stack.format_arn) method.

There is an elegant third alternative using [cdk.Lazy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Lazy.html). However, I believe [Lazy is still broken in Python](https://github.com/aws/jsii/issues/1781). Anyway, here is how it would look in Typescript:

```js
const my_arn = cdk.Lazy.string({
  produce: () =>
    ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup(
      this,
      'test-value-for-my-job-executor-new-function-lambda-arn'
    ),
});
```