# cdk python not fetching value from SSM parameter store even during Deploy Time

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cdk, aws-ssm

I have a line of code that is supposed to get the value for a parameter name in the SSM parameter store. As per documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_ssm/README.html#using-existing-ssm-parameters-in-your-cdk-app)

This is my code

```
    table_name = ssm.StringParameter.from_string_parameter_attributes(self, "activity-details-table-name", parameter_name="/XAZ-1019/activity/table-name").string_value 
    print(table_name)
```

When I do a cdk deploy I only get `${Token[TOKEN.358]}` in the print statement right after

Answer (score 4):

This is the expected behaviour of `from_string_parameter_attributes`.  The `string_value` method returns a [Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html) value, which the CDK converts to a CloudFormation [Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) intrinsic function in the template.

In other words, you are right that the CDK is not fetching the actual value.  It's CloudFormation that gets the value from the SSM Parameter Store at deploy-time.  No matter.  We can merrily pass the opaque token value around in our CDK code, and leave it to the CDK to include the right references in the template.

If you *really* need synth-time resolution of the actual paramater value, there's always [value_from_lookup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ssm/StringParameter.html#aws_cdk.aws_ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup).  It is one of a handful of [context methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html) that has the CDK actually make (and cache) cloud-side lookups itself.

Comment: Cloudformation doesn't get it at deploy time. I am not concerned about synth time as I know it doesn't fetch it then. I was expecting it to get the value at least at deploy time, which it doesn't. The value at deploy time still is the token value

Comment: Your `print` is called during synth, not during deployment. How are you checking the value at deploy time? Your CDK code is only executed to generate the cloudformation template. This generated template is then uploaded to AWS and deployed. That's when the tokens are resolved.

Comment: you mean at deploy time the print statement wont print the actual value that it pulled out and stored into a variable? I am using the name in the variable after the print statement in a `dynamodb..put_item(TableName=table_name ` which gives an error:  validation error detected: Value '${Token[TOKEN.355]}' at 'tableName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+

Comment: This tells me that even at deploy time when I am writing some values to a dynamodb table, it doesn't pull out the actual value when its doing the deploy.

Comment: @user20358  Keep in mind that `cdk deploy` [performs a synth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-deploy) before deploying.  Python code is executed during the synth phase, as gshpychka says.

Comment: so how do I get the value I need from the ssm param when deploying?

Comment: I tried `value_from_lookup`, but that only gives out a dummy value

Comment: @user20358  You are trying to consume the [context variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html#context_construct) before the synth phase has fetched/cached it.  See option #1 in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72806487/1103511) for the workaround.

Comment: @fedonev Thanks. The option #1 wont work because this code will be eventually run in a pipeline. Hardcoding wont work either.

Comment: @user20358 I'm glad to help further, but please first edit your question (or ask a new one) with your use case spelled out. I have answered the OP as written, but more requirements are appearing in the comments.  I don't want to waste your time or mine by guessing what [root problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) you are trying to solve.

Comment: @user20358 no, as I said, your print statement is only called during synth. "deploy time" is when the cloudformation template that was generated during synth gets uploaded to CloudFormation and provisioned. Your code has run long before that happens.

Calling SDK commands like `put_item` will not work because the table doesn't exist at synth time (conceptually).